# iText how to fix cross reference table for signed pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm using itext 7 to sign pdf that has 2 signature fields and itext is printing
`Error occurred while reading cross reference table. Cross reference table will be rebuilt.`
The line that is causing error is

```
new PdfSigner(sourceDoc, signedFile, new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
```

Usually when I got that error I would fix it by copying pdf to new one with code:

```
sourceDocument.copyPagesTo(firstPage, sourceDocument.getNumberOfPages(), targetDocument, firstPage);
```

and then sign targetDocument. It fix cross table problem but it does not copy existing signatures.
So I have added

```
sourceDocument.copyPagesTo(..., new PdfPageFormCopier());
```

and it does copy signatures but in result they are invalid ( because document hash has changed and it affects signatures?)

Is there any chance that document can be fixed so that signatures are intact and another signature can be appended?

I do not control pdf that is being sign because it is client that is sending it to me and somehow he managed to sign it elsewhere (maybe by using older version of itext or open pdf?) despite cross reference problem (or that what caused problem).

Reference table that causes problem in itext7

```
xref
0 60
0000000000 65535 f 
0000175044 00000 n 
0000000000 65536 n 
0000095603 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000086011 00000 n 
0000020754 00000 n 
0000019785 00000 n 
0000019501 00000 n 
0000000212 00000 n 
0000020091 00000 n 
0000057104 00000 n 
0000054819 00000 n 
0000054543 00000 n 
0000020921 00000 n 
0000055414 00000 n 
0000085852 00000 n 
0000083751 00000 n 
0000083466 00000 n 
0000057253 00000 n 
0000084295 00000 n 
0000000000 65536 n 
0000095805 00000 n 
0000000000 65536 n 
0000164295 00000 n 
0000095937 00000 n 
0000096014 00000 n 
0000107919 00000 n 
0000121074 00000 n 
0000120425 00000 n 
0000120265 00000 n 
0000108058 00000 n 
0000120701 00000 n 
0000121221 00000 n 
0000138109 00000 n 
0000137022 00000 n 
0000136863 00000 n 
0000121317 00000 n 
0000137511 00000 n 
0000138253 00000 n 
0000146202 00000 n 
0000145690 00000 n 
0000145530 00000 n 
0000138341 00000 n 
0000145904 00000 n 
0000164151 00000 n 
0000162977 00000 n 
0000162818 00000 n 
0000146341 00000 n 
0000163510 00000 n 
0000000000 65536 n 
0000174805 00000 n 
0000164534 00000 n 
0000164611 00000 n 
0000174666 00000 n 
0000175345 00000 n 
0000175115 00000 n 
0000175251 00000 n 
0000175398 00000 n 
0000175459 00000 n 
trailer
<</Size 60/Info 59 0 R/ID [<2dda6a23fc5d97b5d4e670c84756e5dd><262a30912f11d84731389759bd75bbf9>]/Root 58 0 R>>
startxref
175602
%%EOF
```

itext calls error `file position {0} cross reference entry in this xref subsection.` after reading line `0000000000 65536 n` (third from the top)

Comment: *"Is there any chance that document can be fixed so that signatures are intact and another signature can be appended?"* - The answer to this depends whether the signature covers the broken cross references or not. If they are covered, repairing them will break the signature. If they are not covered, it might be possible to fix them without  breaking the signature. If you share the PDF, we can analyze the issue further.

Comment: I wish i could provider pdf but it contains customer data. Let's say it was signed with broken structure, I cannot make itext to sign it nor fix it now right?

Comment: Document ends with
`trailer
<</Info 59 0 R/ID [<fff96a8bba26c3d5b27b751120cca055><bc9189406be84ec297464a514221406d>]/Root 58 0 R/Size 77/Prev 197258>>
startxref
300480
%%EOF`

Comment: I have tried this tool from MuPDF
https://mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-clean.html
as it says `The clean command pretty prints and rewrites the syntax of a PDF file. It can be used to repair broken files, expand compressed streams, filter out a range of pages, etc. ` but after creating new pdf, signatures are already broken

Comment: Can you search for `/ByteRange[...]` (`...` being 4 integers) in the PDF file and share the matches here? There should be one occurrence for each signature. They document the signed byte ranges. And can you share the file size? With these data we can determine whether one of your signatures covers the whole file or not.

Comment: First signature
`/ByteRange [0 177104 196050 1580 ]`
Second signature
`/ByteRange [0 212340 277878 23120 ] `
File size: My linux shows 300,998 bytes

Comment: *"Second signature `/ByteRange [0 212340 277878 23120 ]`  File size: My linux shows 300,998 bytes"* - That means that the second signature covers the whole file:  277878 + 23120 = 300998... Thus, any repair work inside the existing file will change the hash, and any repair work using an appended new cross reference table will make the second signature not cover a whole revision implied by the cross reference tables in the chain of such tables starting at the final **startxref**. Either way Adobe Reader will complain.

Comment: @mkl thank you for your time. Can I have last question? In other post [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281240/append-mode-requires-a-document-without-errors-even-if-recovery-is-possible) You said that itext7 contains bug related to hybrid-reference file. Is it possible that this file is OK but itext7 cannot handle it properly?

Comment: @JK_codes *"In other post [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47303363/1729265) You said that itext7 contains bug related to hybrid-reference file. Is it possible that this file is OK but itext7 cannot handle it properly?"* - The post you mention is four years old, I assume that bug meanwhile is fixed. Also according to what you shared about your PDF it does not appear to be hybrid-reference. Of course, though, I cannot preclude that there is a different issue in iText which makes it incorrectly assume a broken cross reference in your PDF. For such a preclusion I'd need to analyze the file

Comment: @mkl as I said before I wish I could give you pdf but it contains confidential data. I have edited post and added reference table that is causing problems. Maybe it will help somehow. I'm mostly convinced that file is simply broken and yet was signed by other applications anyway.

Comment: If the `0000000000 65536 n` entries are the only issue with that document, you can override iText's rejecting behavior, see section "Trying To Sign Nonetheless" in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Issue

Eventually you posted the problematic cross reference table. What immediately catches one's eye are multiple entries of this kind:

```
0000000000 65536 n
```

They mean that the corresponding object with a generation number of 65536 is located at offset 0.

This is invalid in two ways:

- The generation number is outside its allowed range:

  | ISO 32000-2, section 7.5.4 "Cross-reference table" |
  | --- |
  | The maximum generation number is 65,535 |

  (One could believe that the producer of that original PDF attempted to cause int16 overflows in PDF processors that rely on valid values here. Are you sure that PDF is from a trustable source?)
- A PDF at offset 0 has the `%PDF-x.y` line and not an object. And even if one feels  that a PDF processor should consider that line a regular comment and skip it, the next indirect object can only match one of all those entries, for the other ones the object number would be incorrect.

*As an aside: This is related to the issue from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58630959/1729265) (with `0000000000 00000 n` entries) and the work-around provided below is essentially the same as provided in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58641601/1729265) to that question. The difference is the additional invalid generation number in your case.*

## Fixing the Cross Reference Tables Keeping the Signatures Intact

In comments you shared the signed byte ranges of the signatures and the size of the PDF:

> First signature `/ByteRange [0 177104 196050 1580 ]`
> Second signature `/ByteRange [0 212340 277878 23120 ]`
> File size: My linux shows 300,998 bytes

Inspecting the byte ranges of the second signature one sees that its second range encompasses 23120 bytes starting at offset 277878, i.e. until the end of the file (277878 + 23120 = 300998).

Thus, any repair work *inside* the existing file will change the hash. And any repair work using an *appended* new cross reference table will at least increase the size of the latest revision and so make the second signature not cover its revision anymore. Either way Adobe Reader will complain.

## Trying To Sign Nonetheless

If you feel venturesome and want to sign that document with the broken cross reference entries nonetheless, you can lead iText into believing the file loaded by your `PdfReader` is not broken after all. You can do so by overriding the corresponding getter methods, instead of

```java
PdfReader sourceDoc = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
```

use

```java
PdfReader sourceDoc = new PdfReader(SOURCE) {
    @Override
    public boolean hasRebuiltXref() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasFixedXref() {
        return false;
    }
};
```

to instantiate your `PdfReader`. Now signing in append mode should be possible, see my proof-of-concept `testSignBrokenXrefForced` in the test class [SignBrokenPdf](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/SignBrokenPdf.java#L94).

**Beware,** the result you get now also is broken, and any signature or PDF validator may reject it. Only do this if you cannot convince your client to produce valid PDFs. And even then you shouldn't. In particular you are responsible if forwarding the signed PDF causes issues in some later processor.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and your time. Instead of doing workarounds I will rather inform client that pdf is broken and we will not take responsibility for signing such document. Best regards

Comment: *"I will rather inform client that pdf is broken and we will not take responsibility for signing such document."* - In the long run this clearly is the better option.